# Update com Array multidimensional

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, array-multidimensional

Estou com  um problema terrível, não consigo fazer update no mysql via PDO, com array que vem de alguns campos do formulário. Já tentei muita coisa e até agora não consigo fazer o update. O array vem nesse formato.

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
            [5] => 6
            [6] => 7
            [7] => 8
            [8] => 9
            [9] => 10
        )

    [url] => Array
        (
            [0] => /ckfinder/userfiles/images/2141.jpg
            [1] => rty
            [2] => rtyrcial.jpg
            [3] => rtyrtrfiles/images/3.jpg
            [4] => rtyrimages/especial.jpg
            [5] => rtyrfiles/images/especial.jpg
            [6] => rtyres/images/especial.jpg
            [7] => /ckfinder/userfiles/images/3.jpg
            [8] => /ckfinder/userfiles/images/Capa1.jpg
            [9] => asd
        )

)
```

TABELA (dados exemplo):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

SQL (PDO):

```
UPDATE via_imagens SET img_url = array[url] WHERE img_capa IS NULL AND img_id = array[id]
```

---

Ok to passando assim:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');

$sql = 'UPDATE via_imagens SET img_url = ? WHERE img_capa IS NULL AND img_id = ?'; 

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

foreach($dados as $item ){
  $stmt->execute(array($dados['url'], $dados['id']));
}
```

Mas tá aparecendo esse erro: **Notice: Array to string conversion in**, apontando para a linha do **$stmt->execute()**;

Comment: -1 pelo titulo "ajuda/urgente" e o uso desnecessário da caixa-alta

Comment: O que tentou fazer até aqui José? Como está o trecho do código que está com problemas. Recomendo também [edit] seu texto. Leia mais em [ask]

Comment: Não consigo da um loop com ambos os valores do array[id] e array[url]. em único laço. To usando foreach. E outra, quando passo o valor em formato de array para a instrução PDO me aparece o Notice: Array to string conversion.

Comment: Alterei minha resposta.

Answer (score 0):

A maneira mais simples de fazer isso é, pegar os valores do array passa-los  por um for e executar o update dentro dele. Caso precise de algo mais restritivo pode uma transação para garantir a integridade da operação.

> Notice: Array to string conversion

Acontece quando você tenta imprimir um valor de array onde a chamada dos índices não está correta, o que vai acontecer é gravar o valor `Array` no banco de dados.

Partindo do ponto que seu array está numa variável chamda `$lista` seu acesso deve ser feito assim: `$lista['url'][1]` será exibido o valor `rty`, o índice `1` deve ser trocar um contador(`$i` por exemplo).

```
$dados = array(); //esse array é tem a url e o id da sua tabela no exemplo

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=teste', 'usuario', 'senha');

$sql = 'UPDATE via_imagens SET img_url = ? WHERE img_capa IS NULL AND img_id = ?';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$total_itens = count($dados['id']);

for($i=0; $i<$total_itens; $i++){
   $stmt->execute(array($dados['url'][$i], $dados['id'][$i]));
}
```